# How can I create a composite primary key (id_x, id_y), where order is unique?

Tags: sql, relational-database, composite-primary-key

I have a similarity matrix between two items and I want to store it as a table in a relational database. Thus, I want the table to have three fields; the id of the first item, the id of the second item and the value of their similarity.

I think about making the two id columns a composite primary key. But how can I ensure that given two items `(x, y)`, the composite key `(id_x, id_y)` is the same as `(id_y, id_x)` so I don't have duplicate entries?

Comment: Add a check constraint, e.g. x < y.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `id` values are using a data type that is well-ordered, one of the simplest ways to achieve this is to enforce a `CHECK` constraint such that `id_x` is less than `id_y`.

This may present some difficulties if you do not have a way to enforce this ordering before entries are created. Some databases allow computation within index definitions, in which case you may be able to define your index on `(MIN(id_x,id_y),MAX(id_x,id_y))` and omit the `CHECK`. (For something like SQL Server, you can put such a computation into an indexed view definition)